# Типы односоставных предложений

Tags: синтаксис

Каким является предложение "Побежал быстро."?

Answer (score 1):

Это неполное двусоставное, если есть контекст, подлежащее восстанавливается.

Answer (score 0):

Неопределённо - личным быть не может: нужно 3 лицо, множ. число. А контекст нужен.

Comment: Вы правы, сама потом поняла, когда отправила)) Сегодня внесла коррективы.

Comment: Вот и прекрасно!